# Jquery Template : Can we use string.Compare() or any other alternative with {{if }} statement

Tags: jquery-templates

```
                {{each HAName }}
                    {{if HAName.Conatins('Bar')}}   
                       Yes
                    {{/if}}
                {{/each}}
                </div>
```

I am using Jquery template.
HAName is of type var/string.

My requirement : 
If HAName contains the word 'Bar' then Yes should be printed.
e.g. HAName=Bar ,HAName=Bar/Lounge , HAName=He goes to Bar

In all the 3 cases Yes should be printed.

As I am new to Jquery template ,  a quick help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

{{if  HAName.toLowerCase().indexOf("bar") >= 0}}